# Can I force some process to execute fork system call, from outside of that process?

Tags: linux, fork

Let's say there is a program, that waits for user input. If user input is "A", program goes to state s_a, and if user input is "B", program goes to state s_b. I don't know which state I need, therefore I want to try both inputs. So I'd like this program to be forked, then I'll be able to type "A" in parent process, and "B" in child process. Is it doable in linux?

So I want something like command

```
$ sudo make_that_process_call_fork_syscall PID
```

I'm going to do it many times per second, so It'll be very inefficient to simply restart that program. (The program is Coq theorem proving assistant).

Comment: Did you consider that there's more than the process to fork? what about its input terminal? what about its (their) now shared file descriptors? While to the letter it's possible to answer the title of your question for some cases, I doubt this will achieve your goal.

Comment: A.B, I guess I can redirect its input/output. And it doesn't write to any files, so I think this approach might work.

Comment: I think you need to implement it in the program itself. You can catch a signal (let's say HUP). Then just `pkill -HUP your_program_name` or `kill -HUP PID`.

Comment: That wouldn't be a "fork" - a fork needs to be a syscall inside the process, and parent and child will know which one is which. What you want to do is to completely "copy" a process to a new process, from the outside. That's an interesting idea, and maybe possible with the `ptrace` interface (at least one could copy the memory of the process), but I don't know a ready-made implementation.

Comment: Why do you want to try both inputs? Why not just wait until the input is provided, then transition to the appropriate state?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot make a program execute `fork` or any other arbitrary system calls unless it has been programmed to do so already.  In general, processes are not allowed to make other processes execute arbitrary code except through defined APIs (such as `ptrace`).  Allowing this would introduce numerous security holes, even if it were limited to `fork`.

Probably the best thing you could try to do is attach to the process at this point with `gdb` and call `fork` manually when it's at the expected prompt.  However, that may have unexpected consequences for the program and would not in general be a good idea.  Since you want to run many copies of the same process, this would not be a scalable approach and you're better off trying something else.